# Stored procedure for dynamic create statement where number of columns keep changing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, create-table, cursors

I need to create a stored procedure to create a dynamic 'create statement' that will generate a new create statement everytime it runs.
I have  table_A that has one column and that column has the list of column names that need to be in the create statement.
Example:

```
     Table_A:  columns   
      abcd   
      hijk   
      defg
```

My create statement should look like:

```
    create table table_B (
    abcd varchar(255),
    hijk  varchar(255),
    defg varchar(255)
    );
```

After a few days the number of columns in Table_A can change/increase/decrease like:

```
  Table_A: columns         
        abcd
        pqrs
        defg
        ghij
```

My create statement should look like:

```
    create table table_B ( 
    abcd varchar(255),
    pqrs  varchar(255),
    defg varchar(255),
    ghij varchar (255)
    );
```

I need to write a stored procedure with cursors involved.

I started with something like:

```
    Delimiter $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_test2 $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test2()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE DONE INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE col1 varchar(255);
    DECLARE curA CURSOR FOR     select col AS column_name from Table_A;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;
    OPEN curA;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_B;
    while done = 0 do  
    fetch next from CurA into col;
    if done = 0 then 
    set @SQL_TXT = concat('CREATE TABLE Table_B (',col1,' varchar(255))');
    -- select @SQL_TXT
    PREPARE stmt_name FROM @SQL_TXT;
    EXECUTE stmt_name;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
    end if;
    end while;
    close curA;
    end

    call sp_test2()
```

This works fine when I have just one row in a table(which is just one column in create table). How do I do it when I have multiple columns.

Comment: This seems a bit like starting to build an RDBMS in an RDBMS

Comment: its just one statement that needs to change.                                              set @SQL_TXT = concat('CREATE TABLE Table_B (',col1,' varchar(255))');

Comment: You're trying to create one table with multiple columns, so you should not be executing the create query every iteration. You loop should be building up a single query, not reassigning the query text every iteration (and not repeating "CREATE TABLE" every iteration).

Comment: Yea I know I need to edit the create statement in such a way that it can loop everytime and add a column. Not sure how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In case it was not clear from my original comment, creating tables like this is almost never a good idea.**

*But if you must, here are some ways....*

Try replacing/rearranging this part (from the original question/problem):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_B;    
while done = 0 do  
fetch next from CurA into col;
if done = 0 then 
set @SQL_TXT = concat('CREATE TABLE Table_B (',col1,' varchar(255))');
-- select @SQL_TXT
PREPARE stmt_name FROM @SQL_TXT;
EXECUTE stmt_name;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
end if;
end while;
close curA;
```

with/like something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_B;
SET @SQL_TXT = '';
while done = 0 do  
    fetch next from CurA into col;
    if done = 0 then 
        set @SQL_TXT = concat(@SQL_TXT, ', `', col1, '` varchar(255)');
    end if;
end while;
close curA;
SET @SQL_TXT = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE Table_B (', SUBSTRING(@SQL_TXT, 2), ')');
PREPARE stmt_name FROM @SQL_TXT;
EXECUTE stmt_name;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
```

The loop builds your field list, the SUBSTRING() removes he leading ',', and the final concat wraps the field list with the actual CREATE.

---

Or you can just build the query like this:

```
SET @SQL_TXT 
   = SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE Table_B ('
                   , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', col, '` VARCHAR(255)') SEPARATOR ',')
                   , ');' AS theQuery
     FROM Table_A
;
```

---

Also not in both cases I delimited the field name with the ` character; field names like "123" cannot be used without being delimited.

Comment: The first option you mentioned loops around multiple times and gives multiple create statements. But the second option using group_concat it works completely fine. Thanks a ton!

Comment: By the "first option", do you mean the cut and paste from the question, or the rearragement of it?

Comment: The rearrangement of it.

Comment: The first option should not do that if the code it replaces is replaced completely. It's loop builds a field list; the "create" is not even added to the string until after the loop.

Comment: i can execute the procedure but when I try to call it gives me an error saying:               You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 SQL.

Comment: Oh, I just added `SET @SQL_TXT = '';` to initialize the session variable... if it were not set on the connection, you would keep getting null, and if it were set at some point, consecutively calls on the same db connection it would've kept appending.

Comment: :I initialized the         `SET  SQL_TXT = '';`         after I opened the cursor and `SET @SQL_TXT = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE Table_B (', SUBSTRING(@SQL_TXT, 2), ')');`  needs to be adjusted too as its its taking the ',' and now it works!! :)

Comment: I have a problem here. I have more that 100 columns in my Table_a that need to be in the create statement but the variable here cannot handle so many columns. Any work around it?

Comment: Maybe `DECLARE sqlTxt TEXT = SELECT CONCAT(....; SET @SQL_TXT = sqlTxt;`? But depends on the charset used, it may just not be possible there are [limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html), "The MySQL maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes". (255 * 100 = 25,500) * the character width.can easily exceed that.

Comment: using the first method you mentioned looping and then creating a table is able to handle any number of columns in create table script actually :)

Comment: When I drop and create the table before I create the cursor the stored proc is not able to handle it?     `create procedure sp_test2()   BEGIN
      drop table if exists tbl_a;
      create table table_a (SELECT  col, datatype FROM Tbl_a);` Can stored proc not handle cursor and create table in the same code?

Comment: If the loop version can handle it, then it has to do with [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: Doesnot work when used with cursor.  By using `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4294967295;` I was able to make the drop and create statements work in the loop and it works perfectly fine!!

Comment: Method1- We can make the stored procedure with cursor work by putting the create table script in the `DECLARE curA CURSOR FOR select *col, datatype from Tbl_a` .  Method2-  `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4294967295;` I was able to make the drop and create statements work in the loop and it works perfectly fine!!